# div visibility toggles continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is simple but I just can't get this bug fixed. I have a `div` which is visible by default and hides on `mouseover` to reveal menu below it, but for some apparent reason, the visibility effect keeps on repeating itself rather than just on `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

I have used following JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#butt").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).closest("button").css("visibility","hidden");
    })
    $("#butt").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).closest("button").css("visibility","visible");
    });
});
```

[the fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hunain/xMwCN/1/)

when you `mouseover` the image in the fiddle it keeps on hiding and appearing...

Comment: I don't think the problem is your javascript but more like css. You can try by removing all your javascript code and you can see it's still the same issue

Comment: The problem is in your CSS. Also, use .hover() ti simplify mouseover and mouseout. Also, don't use a <b> tag just to put an id, those are deprecated, use <span> or <div> instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer which i was looking for, tnax everyone, because i was able to deduce the result by guidelines and answers which everyone provided.

As mentioned, my javascripts hides the div on mouseenter and makes it visible on mouseleave; when mouse is over it is hidden and browser understans this as mouseleave, therefore it was toggling continuously, visible and hide

The code thus now i did is

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#butt").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#butt").css("visibility","hidden");
          })
          $("#info2").mouseleave(function () {
            $("#butt").css("visibility","visible");
          });
    });
```

Thus mouseleave is on the div which is beneath it which i want to show on mousenter of the above div

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of your fiddle is very logical. You try to hide something on mouseover, but when the item effectively disappear, the mouse is not on it anymore! So there is a mouseout! That's why it flickers, just try to implement behaviors that are a little bit more logical than that and you will not have that kind of problem anymore.

A sample that does not flicker:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#butt").mouseover(function () {
        $("span", $(this)).css("visibility","hidden");
      })
      $("#butt").mouseout(function () {
        $("span", $(this)).css("visibility","visible");
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xMwCN/5/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is because the mouseout triggers when the button is hidden, and because the cursor is still in the same place when mouseout triggers, it triggers mouseover. I suggest you wrap your button in a container and wire up the mouseover/mouseout on the container instead.  Then you can hide/show the button inside. On your fiddle you're hiding the b and not the button.  Perhaps instead of

```
$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

it should be

```
$('button', this).css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

I also noticed your css hover styles are affecting this as well.

Comment: ok i have done what you have suggested and edited the code by what you mentioned, but still no result, by following your syntax it repeats the same pattern, and now by using the new edited code, there is no result, meaning no toggling

Comment: Yes - see my last comment in the answer - your hover styles are affecting it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use css attribute `opacity` instead of `visibility` otherwise the element wont be there anymore activating the mouse event again.

I have [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xMwCN/8/) with the Gray Box going invisible on mouseover

But what you want to do here is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#butt").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css("opacity","0");
          })
          $("#butt").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("opacity","1");
          });
    });
```

And also your css was changing the display, witch was causing some visibility problems, you might want to change it to:

```
.info {
    display: none;
}
```

Or otherwise check which element need to have the :hover property.

Cheers.

Comment: loot at this fiddle now, this the problem i am having
http://jsfiddle.net/Hunain/xMwCN/9/

Comment: @Hunain The problem you're facing in this scenario is relative to the positioning of the elements, they are really confusing. Let me see if i got this straight, you want the box with the UL to be beneath the Box that will disapear on mouse over?

Comment: @Hunain That's great! You should mark your own answer as the official for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need a fixed height for the panel. It is because the height of image is 400px, when you hover it, the image hide and show the menu. However, the menu height is less than 400px. Now you are not hovering the panel and show the image again and repeating the problem. The simplest fix is set height to the panel.

```
.panel { height:400px;}
.panel ul{ margin:0;}
```

Hope this can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an acceptable solution, you can just do the following to avoid flickering:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".panel").mouseover(function () {
        $("#butt").css("visibility","hidden");
      })
      $(".panel").mouseout(function () {
        $("#butt").css("visibility","visible");
      });
});
```

This removes the text when you hover over the entire panel and then it appears on mouseout.  You cannot hide a div and call mouseout on that div, the div with the hover must stay there the entire time to avoid flickering problems.